# Event trigger assigned through public variable not firing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am confused about the reason of my Event not being fired through script in this case.

The drop-down on the GameObject does show all the EventStrings already defined in the project, but when I attempt to trigger the event later on using the eventName variable, it fails :

```
//public variables
public Constants.EventStrings eventName;

// later in the script 
EventManager.TriggerEvent(new GameEvent(eventName));
```

Triggering events anywhere else in the project works without problems, so I suppose the problem stems from how I'm passing the eventName value?

I usually trigger events in the rest of the project the following way without issues :

```
EventManager.TriggerEvent(new GameEvent(Constants.EventStrings.EVENT_STRING));
```

Comment: What is `GameEvent`? What does`EventManager.TriggerEvent ` do? And what exactly is supposed to happen? If you always generate a new GameEvent instance  (using `new`) when triggering the event, will there be anyone who listens/reacts to this event?

Comment: @derHugo - Yes, there is a listener in the scene as well which reacts to the event being fired. `EventManager.TriggerEvent` triggers the events defined in a public class `Constants`. Here is what TriggerEvent does (in short) : `TriggerEvent(GameEvent gEvent) { if (instance.eventDictionary.TryGetValue(gEvent.Name, out thisEvent)) { thisEvent.Invoke(gEvent); }}` - if firing the event the usual way (without using the eventName public variable), everything works fine.